# Retrieving list from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an Android app where I am using Firebase to store a list of information. I am able to store the information on the real time database without an issue, but the problem I am currently having is trying to figure out how to retrieve the list when new content is added.

When I add, change, or delete values in the list, none of the `childEventListener`s are called.

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference toDatabase;

...

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_world_play_hide);

        hideAvatar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hideAvatar);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        toDatabase = database.getReference("jsierra");

        ...

        hideAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 ...

                getCurrentLocation();
                currentCoordinates = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                data store = new data(currentCoordinates);

                toDatabase.push().setValue(store);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentCoordinates));
            }
        });
    }

protected void onStart() {
        apiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseReference test = toDatabase.child("jsierra");

        test.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                givenData = dataSnapshot.getValue(data.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                givenData = dataSnapshot.getValue(data.class);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                givenData = dataSnapshot.getValue(data.class);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                givenData = dataSnapshot.getValue(data.class);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Child Moved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test` reference is incorrect.  Change:

```
DatabaseReference test = toDatabase.child("jsierra");
```

to:

```
DatabaseReference test = database.getReference("jsierra");
```

Comment: I changed it and got an error "cannot resolve method child". I looked at FirebaseDatabase API and child is not part of it. I tried getReference and it worked! Thanks for the help!